# MySQL 5.1 memory leak when processing large numbers of rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP 5 script which loops through a MySQL table (approx. 600,000 rows), and for each row, maintains approx. 16 other tables of summarised information based on columns on each row of the source table (this is done by checking if the summary row exists, and if so, update it, else insert it).

The problem is that as the process continues, the mysqld.exe process eats up more and more memory until it exhausts the system and crashes the PHP script. The PHP script is not gaining memory, only the mysqld.exe process. In the PHP script, each read from a table is free'd (`$resultset->free()` statement) so all should be well.

Comment: You're going to have to show some code... what kind of queries are you running, any temp tables or variables, etc...  The odds are your process could be optimized to summarize everything at once rather than a row at a time.

Comment: You should also look at/post your `my.cnf` (or maybe it's `my.ini` in Windows).  There are memory limits in there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not hitting the maximum execution time? How fast is your query when you execute it directly?

Comment: Thanks for the answers - it wasnt MySQL, but a COM call to a third-party driver that was using the memory - my bad :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers - it wasnt MySQL, but a COM call to a third-party driver that was using the memory - my bad :)